# Windows 7 Taskbar and Systray are reset after a power outage

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I've lost power on my win7 system about 30 times over the last three years. When the system boots back up, the taskbar and systray are completely reset to their defaults.

- All custom toolbars are removed
- The system tray icons are reset

The only modifications that remain are the "pinned" apps, probably because they are set by shortcuts in a system folder.

I'm guessing I'm not alone in experiencing this.

How do you make Windows 7 remember the taskbar and systray states after a power outage?

[image: Windows 7 taskbar resets after losing power]

Comment: No idea, why windows is behaving that way. (You could try restoring the registry from backup if you have one, it might save you the trouble of setting it all up again.) Using a UPS with communications cable could safely run your system on battery when the power goes out and shutdown your machine when the battery gets low so it goes down gracefully before the battery loses power entirely. For short outages it just keeps your machine running. Might not be that bad of an idea if your line power is that unreliable.

Comment: Believe me, I've had "battery backup/UPS" on my shopping list for a long time. Don't think it'll ever happen at this point.

Comment: Jeff, The taskbar setup is saved during a logoff session. Technically speaking, in case of sudden reboot/crashes, the previously saved taskbar values should be used as a fallback mechanism. Not sure why it doesn't happen. If you need a script solution to backup Taskbar automatically at startup, let me know.

Comment: w32sh, that would be great. If you'd like to create an answer with the script, I'll test it out. What is the name of the file that's responsible for saving the taskbar values? Does it need to be copied via a shadow copy or can it be copied normally? Oh and by the way, the systray is also reset.

Comment: Technically (i.e. pedantry ahead), [there is no such thing as the "system tray"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583) - you're thinking of the notification area. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried performing "System Restore"?

If there's a recent restore point before the changes on the taskbar occurred, it's possible the changes will be reverted. Just be sure you haven't installed any programs after the restore point because it will be deleted and you have to reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979155) is your problem. However, we can't download it and supply. You may have to talk to Microsoft customer service for their hotfix.